# How to extend word underline to end of line with Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I am trying to create a header where the underline completely extends horizontally to the end of the document, but I cannot find out how to do this.

Answer (score 21):

You can achieve a similar effect by:

1. Highlighting the text
2. Opening **Format** > **Paragraph styles** > **Borders and shading...**
3. Choosing a bottom border
4. Pressing **Apply**

Comment: This is what i was looking for, not the horizontal line.

Comment: This did the trick. This is using the Borders method. (and also tried the Insert > Horizontal line method). https://i.imgur.com/JcSdHce.png

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 13):

If you're trying to do the same thing I was - extend the underline on the *same* line after some text - here's the trick:

The fix is to insert a special character. Go to Insert → Special Characters → Format & Whitespace → Whitespace, and select the ninth from the left on the top row: PUNCTUATION SPACE or U+2008. It presents a uniform space for Docs to underline. Then copy it (ctrl+c) and paste it (ctrl-v) where you need it.

Word to the wise, SAVE these instructions. I had been doing this to create headings in my resume for months, but suddenly Docs started messing up the formatting of the text. I removed the extra underlined parts and re-inserted the special characters and now it's working again.

Answer (score 3):

Normal spaces can be underlined as long as there is a non-space character to the **right** of them. You can abuse this by letting the line end with any printable symbol with white color so that it wont be visible.

Answer (score 2):

Insert -> Special Character -> Punctuation -> Dash/Connector -> Low Line

Answer (score 1):

I needed an underline that extended to the end of the line, but started at an arbitrary point (like for a name entry field), so the first answer didn't work for me.

A bit similar to that method though, you can use a table with a single border to achieve a similar effect.

First, insert a 2x1 table.

[image: 2x1 Table]

Add the text that shouldn't be underlined on the left, and the text that should on the right.

[image: 2x1 Table with contents]

Remove the cell padding (**Format > Table > Table Properties**, set **Cell padding** and **Minimum row height** (if applicable) to 0).

[image: 2x1 Table with contents but no cell padding]

Drag the inner cell wall to whatever point you like.

[image: 2x1 Table with left cell fitted]

Select the entire table and set the **Border width** to 0.

[image: 2x1 Table with zero-width borders]

Finally, click on the left cell and select its bottom border,

[image: How to select that border via the GUI]

And set its width to some non-zero value.
[image: Tada! Underlined Text!]

Answer (score 0):

Use spaces all the way, then at the end of the line put a random letter that's colour is white. It will look like the whole line is underlined.

Answer (score -1):

Insert > Horizontal Line

This should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

The horizontal line insisted on extra space. I changed its font size to 1. It worked well enough for me.